# Telerik MVC grid, ajax binding and MVC areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, telerik

I changed my project and separated my files into areas but now my ajax bind dont work.

```
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("GridAjax","Products"))
```

GridAjax is action while Products is controller.

Products controller is in my Areas/user/controllers

but i got url request like

```
http://localhost:1056/user/null
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataBinding.Ajax().Select("GridAjax", "Products", new { area = "user" })
```

The Select() method has a few overloads that allow to specify other routing options.

Comment: I'd also recommend to take a look at T4MVC, as it allows to strongly type routes instead of using literal strings. More information here:[http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/)